# Nokogiri get elements if exist or not

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

```
Quite simply can you do a conditional scrape, i.e. I want an <a> 
tag within a parent, and if a <span> is contained within that parent
(so the span is holding the <a>, instead of the parent), I still want
to drill into the span regardless for the <a>
```

---

Hopefully this example will provide enough details.

```
<tr>
    <td>1989</td>
    <td>
      <i>
       <a href="/wiki/Always_(1989_film)" title="Always (1989 film)">Always</a>
     </i>
    </td>
     <td>Pete Sandich</td>
</tr>
```

I can access the `<a>` fine using:

`all_links = doca.search('//tr//td//i//a[@href]')`

But what I want to know is can I also add a conditional, so if there is a span surrounding the `<a>`, can this be put in the search?

```
 <tr>
    <td>1989</td>
    <td>
      <i>
       <span>
         <a href="/wiki/Always_(1989_film)" title="Always (1989 film)">Always</a>
       </span>
     </i>
    </td>
     <td>Pete Sandich</td>
</tr>
```

So is there a way to conditionally grab the `<a>`, something like so:

`all_links = doca.search('//tr//td//i//?span//a[@href]')`

Where ?span would be a conditional - i.e. if a span is there, then enter that level, and then enter the link.

And if no span is there then skip it and just enter the link.

Thanks in advance, greatly appreciate any help!

Shane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go :

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse <<-eot
<tr>
    <td>1989</td>
    <td>
      <i>
       <span>
         <a href='/wiki2/Always_(1989_film)' title='Always (1989 film)'>Always</a>
       </span>
     </i>
    </td>
        <td>
      <i>
         <a href='/wiki1/Always_(1989_film)' title='Always (1989 film)'>Always</a>
     </i>
    </td>
     <td>Pete Sandich</td>
</tr>
eot

# xpath expression will grab a tag if it is wrapped inside the span tag
node = doc.xpath("//tr//i//a[name(./..)='span']")
p node.size # => 1
p node.map{ |n| n['href'] } # => ["/wiki2/Always_(1989_film)"]
```

Comment: Appreciate the help, but this won't work with the structure of my program. 


As it turns out though, the original line:


`all_links = doca.search('//tr//td//i//a[@href]')`


will suffice for my program I think. Thanks again though.

Comment: Actually, curiously; would this still grab the `<a>` tag, even if no span was present? Apologies, but I am not so familiar and am still learning ruby. Thanks again :)

Comment: @shanehoban No this code will grab all `a` tags which are wrapped in `span`.. otherwise not..

Comment: Ah I see, I was looking for a conditional - so if there is a `span`, get the `a` within the span, otherwise, get the `a` within the parent `i` tag.

Comment: @shanehoban Probably I could get you a better solution as you commented,if you can provide the exact html you are having..This one is not matching with your comment... :)